# How to fix generated email from BlueSpice Media Wiki for new users to supply actual name?

Tags: php, email, mediawiki, site-maintenance, bugs

I have a standard install of BlueSpice on top of Media Wiki.  When a new user is created I get an email with the body:

> The user http://wiki.example.com/index.php/User:NameHere with real name $2 was created.

The `$2` should be substituted with the actual real name of the user, so there is a bug here.  Where can I locate the code in the install the corresponds to this and how do I cause it to make the substitution?  It seems the `$1` worked with the `User:NameHere`, so not sure why the `$2` didn't also get substituted. I imagine this is in somewhere in the php code.

Doing a grep I find:

```
# cd ~/public_html
# grep -R "with real name" .
./extensions/BlueSpiceExtensions/Notifications/i18n/en.json:    "bs-notifications-email-addaccount": "The user $1 with real name $2 was created.",
```

The full `en.json` file at that location is:

```
{
    "@metadata": {
        "authors": [
            "Swidmann"
        ]
    },
    "bs-notifications-desc": "Sends notifications on user selected changes",
    "prefs-notifications": "Notifications",
    "prefs-echo-extended": "Advanced system settings",
    "bs-notifications-pref-notifyns": "Only notify for changes in these namespaces:",
    "bs-notifications-pref-notifynominor": "No notification for minor changes",
    "bs-notifications-pref-active": "Enable notifications",
    "bs-echo-anon-user": "anonymous",
    "bs-echo-unknown-user": "unknown",
    "bs-echo-page-edit": "The page [[:$1]] has been changed",
    "bs-echo-page-create": "The page  [[:$1]] was created",
    "bs-echo-page-delete": "The page [[:$1]] has been deleted",
    "bs-echo-page-move": "The page [[:$1]] has been moved",
    "bs-echo-page-newuser": "The user $1 was created.",
    "bs-echo-page-shoutbox": "A new ShoutBox message on the site [[:$1]].",
    "bs-notifications-email-new-subject": "Page $1 {{GENDER:$2|created}} by $2",
    "bs-notifications-email-new": "The page \"$1\" was {{GENDER:$2|created}} by $2.\n\nComment:\n $3 \nYou can visit the page following this link:\n$4\n",
    "bs-notifications-email-edit-subject": "Page $1 {{GENDER:$2|edited}} by $2",
    "bs-notifications-email-edit": "The page \"$1\" was {{GENDER:$2|edited}} by $2.\n\nComment:\n $3 \nYou can visit the page following this link:\n$4.\n\nIf you only want to see the changes, follow this link:\n$5\n",
    "bs-notifications-email-move-subject": "Page $1 {{GENDER:$2|moved}} by $2",
    "bs-notifications-email-move": "The page \"$1\" was {{GENDER:$2|moved}} to $3 by $2. You can visit the page following this link:\n$4\n",
    "bs-notifications-email-delete-subject": "Page $1 {{GENDER:$2|deleted}} by $2",
    "bs-notifications-email-delete": "The page \"$1\" was {{GENDER:$2|deleted}} by $2.\n\nThis was the reason:\n$3",
    "bs-notifications-email-addaccount-subject": "User $1 created",
    "bs-notifications-email-addaccount": "The user $1 with real name $2 was created.",
    "bs-notifications-email-shout-subject": "$2 {{GENDER:$2|posted}} a message on page $1",
    "bs-notifications-email-shout": "$2 {{GENDER:$2|posted}} a message on page \"$1\".\n\nMessage:\n$3\n\nYou can visit the page following this link:\n$4.\n",
    "echo-category-title-bs-create-cat": "Notification for new pages",
    "echo-category-title-bs-edit-cat": "Notification for edits",
    "echo-category-title-bs-move-cat": "Notification for moves",
    "echo-category-title-bs-delete-cat": "Notification for deletions",
    "echo-category-title-bs-newuser-cat": "Notification for new users (administrators only)",
    "echo-category-title-bs-shoutbox-cat": "Notification for messages on watched pages (shoutbox)"
}
```

Unclear what the solution is though.  Where is the shifted set of arguments where another needs to be inserted to fill `$2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the source files for some part of the message, such as `with real name $2 was created`. You will find some message files - either JSON files, or PHP array, but in any case, a key-value format, where the key tells you the name of the message. You can then search for that name in the source. See the [message interface](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Messages_API) for how you can add parameters to a message.